# Ungroup with changing transform

Tags: transforms, groups

When I delete the group, my character loses the group rotation and scale, so how do I take my mesh out of a group without losing the transform? And <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> makes my mesh disappear

Answer (score 1):

Select the children objects, pres <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Clear Parent And Keep Transformations*.
That way, you unset these objects' parent while keeping them wherever they are.

Then do whatever you want with your used-to-be parent object.